# Away3D Context3D not available

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.6, away3d

I'm checking out Flash's 3D capabilities with [Away3D](http://www.away3D.com), and I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.flashmagazine.com/Tutorials/detail/away3d_4_basics_-_a_simple_class_explained/). I've run into a major problem though. Everytime I run my project in the browser, I get this error:

> Error #2044: Unhandled ErrorEvent:. text=Error #3702: Context3D not available.

I can't see where this error comes from, but it happens after my constructor function ends and before the `ENTER_FRAME` handler starts.

My code is like this:

```
package {
    import away3d.containers.View3D;
    import away3d.entities.Mesh;
    import away3d.materials.ColorMaterial;
    import away3d.primitives.SphereGeometry;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    [SWF(backgroundColor="#000000", frameRate="60", width="1024", height="768")]
    public class TestAway extends Sprite {
        private var view:View3D;

        public function TestAway() {
            view=new View3D();
            addChild(view);
            var sphereGeometry:SphereGeometry=new SphereGeometry(350);
            var sphereMaterial:ColorMaterial=new ColorMaterial(0xff0000);
            var mesh:Mesh=new Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
            view.scene.addChild(mesh);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }


        private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
            view.render();
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the wierd thing is, when I run it on my browser (FP 11.2), it doesn't work (gives that error), but I can run the swf from the desktop perfectly.

Also, the example file on the tutorial page runs perfectly. What setting is missing, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you set `<param name="wmode" value="direct">`?

Comment: Well, yes I did, but as the new html wrapper uses swfObject by default, I needed to add the parameter in the swfObject params object too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it appears you need to set `wmode` as `direct` to make use of the 3D API.

While I had seen this bit of info, the html wrapper needs to be modified in 3 places for it to work on all configurations:

(1) In the javascript for `swfObject`

```
params.wmode = "direct";
```

(2) In the `<object>` tag

```
<param name="wmode" value="direct" />
```

and (3) in the `<object>` tag for IE

```
 <param name="wmode" value="direct" />
```

Answer (score 5):

To extend further helpful hints, if you are trying to open an application that uses Context3D in a new NativeWindow, you need to make sure that the you specify the renderMode in the NativeWindowInitOptions that gets passed into the NativeWindow. The render mode cannot change after the Native Window gets created.

```
// New window.
options = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
options.renderMode = "direct";
options.transparent = true;
options.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.NONE;
nativeWindow = new NativeWindow( options );
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting here hoping to help anyone with the same problem, but exporting to AIR.

Edit the app descriptor.xml and change the value to of rendermode to:

```
<renderMode>direct</renderMode>
```

Hope it helps